# Generated PDF file is blank when exported more than 1000 records

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation, ireport

I am using *iReport 5.0.1* and had created a report. In this reports we are fetching data from database.

And while previewing this report in *XLS* and *HTML* data is visible but while previewing this report in *PDF* a blank file is displayed. This problem occurs when more than 1000 records are coming otherwise this works fine. Please suggest some solution for exporting more than 1000 rows in *PDF*.

Comment: Did you try to generate *PDF* with *Java* code?

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to  out of memory. You may increase tomcat memory size configuration if you are using tomcat apache

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a parameter as like - parameters.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION",Boolean.FALSE); This worked for me.